# Delayed scroll position for fixed element on android device

Tags: android, jquery, css

I have an element that becomes fixed when scrolling > 145px, it then becomes unfixed when scrolling < 145px.

It works fine on desktops, but it seems to react slower on mobile devices. On Android the fixed element would stay fixed all the way to the top of page, with a delay of about 2 seconds, before the mobile browser realises it's less than 145px from the top.

How do I stop the delay?

**jQuery**

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 145) {
        if ($("#latestWrapper").css('position') !== 'fixed') {
            $("#latestWrapper").css("position", "fixed");
            $("#latestWrapper").css("top", "0px");
        }
    } else {
        if ($("#AddFixedLatest").css('position') !== 'static') {
            $("#latestWrapper").css("position", "absolute");
            $("#latestWrapper").css("top", "145px");
        }
    }
});
```

**CSS**

```
div#latestWrapper {
    height:50px;
    top:145px;
    width:100%;
    pointer-events:none;
    text-align:left;
    z-index:1;
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Help appreciated.

Comment: mobile phones are slower processing than desktops?

Comment: @mituw16 I was thinking it was something to do with the way mobile devices use touch scroll.

Comment: You may want to look into Jquery Mobile.

Comment: @Cam I know of it but my site is responsive so it's unneeded, I was also under the impression that jQuery Mobile isn't meant to be for responsive sites?

Comment: Its not necessary thats for sure. Just something to think about. I dont believe that responsive or not would matter

Comment: @Cam I've tried importing it before and it messed upa  lot of thigns with my site, I think next time I'll consider implementing before building :)

Comment: Here is something.. Try this code, and see what pops up when you scale the screen in on your android device. http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/4fDFW/  You may want to play with the font size. Android screen resolutions are strangely different.

Comment: Nm, it appears droid does not like my code..

Comment: @Cam Thanks for the effort, I might have found something for now, just trying it out.

Comment: I saw this and thought maybe there is a solution in here you can use. http://blog.jonathanargentiero.com/?p=134

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible fix. Not sure if this will work. It will actually require your resize to check itself every few seconds. Not sure if this will work. Give it a shot.

```
var delay = (function(){
  var timer = 0;
  return function(callback, ms){
  clearTimeout (timer);
  timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
  };
})();

$(window).scroll(function () {
   delay(function(){
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 145) {
    if ($("#latestWrapper").css('position') !== 'fixed') {
        $("#latestWrapper").css("position", "fixed");
        $("#latestWrapper").css("top", "0px");
    }
} else {
    if ($("#AddFixedLatest").css('position') !== 'static') {
        $("#latestWrapper").css("position", "absolute");
        $("#latestWrapper").css("top", "145px");
    }
}
 }, 100);
});
```

Comment: This would force the scroll to evaluate itself everytime the window is scrolled. I think this might work... ITs worth a shot.